# Accessing wcf web service with powershell2

Tags: wcf, powershell, powershell-2.0, wshttpbinding, wcf-endpoint

I'm trying to write a cmdlet that accesses one of my wcf webservices.

I've been looking at the new cmdlet : New-WebServiceProxy, but it only really seems capable of consuming ASMX webservices.

I've seen this article; which is focussed around Powershell v1.0
I'd rather use a better method (if one exists).
http://keithhill.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5A8D2641E0963A97!645.entry

From my other .net apps that consume this webservice, here's the sort of configuration i use;

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="819200" maxArrayLength="1638400" maxBytesPerRead="409600" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://myServer/MyService/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Anyone wanna advise me?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you are going to want to create a client side proxy object, compile that into a .NET assembly, create that proxy and program against it in PowerShell.  New-WebServiceProxy was written to allow you to do that.  I'm surprised that it would only work against ASMX services?  Perhaps it isn't working for you because you don't have a MEX endpoint defined in your config file?  See this [article on how to create a MEX endpoint](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2006/11/09/WCF-Part-4-_3A00_-Make-your-service-visible-through-metadata.aspx) that will enable proxy generation for your web service.